# Retain fetched old record in a variable after SaveChanges() are called in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have written a function where I am updating an Employee's details.
On each successful update I have to log the old record for the Employee to the history table.

So I need to keep the old record in memory variable and then once the SaveChanges() are done successfully, I have to pass it to LogHistory() which accepts an Employee object and add an entry with the old employee record to Employee_History table.

### Problem:

In the code below once SaveChanges() is called, the variable oldEmployee also gets updated and adds the updated Employee record instead of adding the Old Employee details.

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int employeeID, Employee personalInfo)
        {
            var employee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(clnt => clnt.PK_EmployeeID == employeeID);
            var oldEmployee = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(clnt => clnt.PK_EmployeeID == employeeID);
            if (employee != null)
            {
                employee.FirstName = personalInfo.FirstName;
                employee.LastName = personalInfo.LastName;

                //Update Client details
                context.SaveChanges();

                //Logging History for previous Client details
                context.LogTransaction(oldEmployee);
            }
        }
```

Please suggest and help me in overcoming this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Both variables `employee` and `oldEmployee` point to the same reference, the employee that you're updating and saving. You have to create a copy of the `employee` before modifying it and submit that to the  logging.

You can create a copy in various ways. One of them is by using `CurrentValues`:

```
var oldEmployee = context.Entry(employee).CurrentValues.ToObject();
```

Or simply create a new employee and copy the properties.

Comment: I am using ObjectContext api and its CurrentValues doesn't have .ToObject().

Comment: Ah. Well, it's just one way to create a copy. You can choose any other clone pattern available. The gist is that you have to create a copy. You may even consider refactoring you application toward the DbContext API, which has many more benefits.

Comment: Yes looking for a Clone pattern but doesn't seems to find one working for me.

Comment: You know that 2 minutes after mentioned it? Anyway, a cloning method is beyond the scope of this question. Feel free to ask a new question if you need more specific help.